# scala companion object templates (Iterator.tabulate)

Tags: scala

I'm new to `scala` and struggling with the documentation a little bit. I was looking at a piece of code in the `spark` codebase (cosine similarity for `RowMatrix`) and saw that they use `Iterator.tabulate`. Not knowing what that function does I looked in the [scala API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Iterator), only to find out the function does not exist. Except that it does exist, because I can use it in the `repl` (hmm, maybe I'm looking at the wrong API docs version ... no, this this is the current version).

After a bit of searching I find out that `tabulate` is defined (at least) in `scala.collection.generic.SeqFactory` and `scala.collection.generic.TraversableFactory`. These two however appear not the be connected in the dependency graph. I can't find any path between the two, and hence no way of actually knowing - from looking at the API docs - that `.tabulate` even exists.

So the question is: how do you find `.tabulate` and it's documentation from looking at the API docs for the class (say `Iterator` or `Seq`). Do I just have to google my way around it, or is there some magic button in the scala docs that will make the thing appear?

This doesn't seem to be limited to just `.tabulate` but a more common issue (at least for me), looking at library code functions seem to exist that are never mentioned in the API. Another example is

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.toBreeze
```

I still don't know if that function exists, some code seems to use it, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala source code all logic of *Iterator* defined in one file [Iterator.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala). Function `tabulate` that you're looking for is defined in [`object Iterator`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L84-L90) in Scala API you make search by `trait Iterator` so this is why you can't find it.

In right corner of [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Iterator) you can switch to *object iterator* and here you will find [Iterator$@tabulate](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator$@tabulate[A](end:Int)(f:Int=>A):Iterator[A]) util function.

Comment: ah, I knew it had to be something simple like that. I thought the `O` and `T` were just showing it's both an object and a trait. Didn't even try clicking them, not the best UI design ever. Also just noticed that the top right corner has related documentation.